# What is the simpliest way to build one jar for multiple modules with Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, jar, build, module

-
-- core (src/main/java)
-- dao (src/main/java)
-- models (src/main/java)
-- main (src/main/java)
What is the simpliest way to build **one** **jar** with main class

for *multiple* *modules* with Gradle and

copy *all classes* and *all resources*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your project is modeled as a multi-project build you can create the following task in the `build.gradle` file of your root project.

```
task uberJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: subprojects.assemble) {
    subprojects.each { project ->
        from project.configurations.archives.allArtifacts.files.collect { zipTree(it) }
    }

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': '<your-main-class>'
    }
}
```

You will also have to set the main class in your JAR manifest.

Comment: THANK YOU! For my sourceSets configuration occures Error:(5, 0) Could not find property 'sourceSets' on project ':dao'.
<a href="openFile:...\build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: Could you provide an example for it?